# Deserialization of java.util.time.LocalDateTime to joda LocalDateTime

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime

I've got REST webservice exposing resources with creation date. It is written in Java 8 - using LocalDateTime. Jackson 2 is serializing it to:

`"createdDate": [2016, 5, 19, 18, 6, 59, 639000000]`

In other application my goal is to consume this rest, but there is only Java 7, so I decided to use joda-time library in DTO. I've set up RestTemplate like this:

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter e = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        e.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        messageConverters.add(e);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<NewUserData> request = new HttpEntity<>(user, headers);
```

POST is successful, however while deserializing answer (with createdDate field from above) exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Value 696000000 for millisOfSecond must be in the range [0,999] (through reference chain: com.foobar.dto.user.UserItem["createdDate"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Value 696000000 for millisOfSecond must be in the range [0,999] (through reference chain: com.foobar.dto.user.UserDisplayItem["createdDate"])
```

My dependencies looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Should I write my own Jackson deserializer or maybe i could use other library/version?

Comment: Why do you serialize it that way instead of with a string date format?

Comment: How to serialize it to string format? I'm not configuring it in any way - just using Spring 4 RestController having jackson dependencies jackson-datatype-jsr310 and jackson-databind.

Comment: You can use `@JsonFormat` to declare a format string for your date types. Choose a format that both versions of `LocalDateTime` can serialize/deserialize.

Comment: Jackson serializes dates to numeric values by default. This can be changed by disabling `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`. The question will still stand though, as dates will be serialised with nanosecond precision which will fail when deserialized by the joda module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem. Here is my new jackson configuration on server (instead of using default):

```
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(customMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Registering module, disabling writing dates as timestamps and registering JavaTimeModule did the job. Thanks to this, server serialized dates to:

```
"createdDate":"2016-06-07T15:15:25"
```

In client application i had to change jackson configuration adding:

```
mapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe Jackson serializes Java 8 temporal types with [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) precision by default, while Joda-Time only supports [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). What you'd need in your server written in Java 8 is to serialize the [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) property as `"createdDate": [2016, 5, 19, 18, 6, 59, 639]` instead of `"createdDate": [2016, 5, 19, 18, 6, 59, 639000000]`.

You can change this behaviour in your Java 8 server by configuring the `ObjectMapper` instance you're using for serialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ... //this is the instance used to serialize the data
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
```

In case you cannot or do not want to change the Java 8 server, Jackson has a corresponding `DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` flag. Sadly, I don't think the [joda module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) supports it at the moment (see [implementation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java#L74)). Because of this, I think your only option right now is to implement a custom deserializer, or better yet, submit a PR with the improvement to joda module.

Comment: Correct, Joda-Time has a resolution of milliseconds for up to 3 digits of decimal fraction of a second: [“The library internally uses a millisecond instant”](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). In contrast, the java.time classes have a resolution of nanoseconds (9 digits of decimal fraction of a second): the `Instant` class  [“…stores a long representing epoch-seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

Comment: Server is written with Spring 4 @RestController, so I'm not configuring Jackson in any way (see my comment under question). Of course I can, but what should I do in situation, when I can't change this? Should I manually map json with custom deserializer?

Comment: I have updated my answert with what can be done on the java 7 server to handle the date with nanosecond precision.